# How to deal with video frames in simulink

Tags: simulink

I am working on videos in simulink.As we know that multimedia file block reads one frame at a time so when I will attach it with matlab function block it should read one frame at a time with imread command. If I double click the matlab function block (as shown at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dggujd&s=6) then you will see that I have to give the name of the function as written in matlab mfile along with the input; which in this case is video(named as convid.avi). I am reading one frame at a time but I have given the whole video as an argument to the matlab function.This is the problem how can I resolve it.What should be given as an argument in matlab function block rather than the whole video.I have also uploaded my model at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=55jggw&s=6. The code which I am using for vidfunc is:

```
function h=vidfunc(u)
a=imread(u); % read frame
BW = edge(a,'sobel'); %sobel edge detection
[H,thetaa,rhoo]=hough(BW); % Hough Transform
P = houghpeaks(H,6,'threshold',ceil(0.5*max(H(:))));
lines=houghlines(BW,thetaa,rhoo,P,'FillGap',15,'Minlength',15)
figure,imshow(I),hold on
for k = 1:length(lines) % Draw lines
 xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
 z(k)=lines(k).point2(2);
 plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',1,'Color','green');
 end
 h=z(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the meat of the work done in this "Simulink" model is actually being performed by your MATLAB function.  So the answer to this question is going to largely rely on what that function is actually doing.  Specifically, what is the expected input to `vidfunc`, and what is this function's output?  I suspect that this function may need to be revised to fit into your model.

To debug your model, it's useful to think about what the signal output is from each block.  At each time step, your `From Multimedia File` block will output a single image frame, which according to the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/frommultimediafile.html) looks to be structured as an

> M-by-N-by-P color video signal where P is the number of color planes.

Moving downstream, we next come to the `Color Space Conversion` block, which in this case looks like it will most likely output an image frame in the form of an M-by-N matrix (where each element of the matrix corresponds to the image's intensity at that pixel).

Now we come to the interesting part -- the `MATLAB Fcn` block.  As we just saw, the input to this block will be an M-by-N matrix representing a single image frame.  When you look in the parameter dialog box for the `MATLAB Fcn` block, the input to this block is represented by the variable `u`.  Therefore, to execute the `vidfunc` function on the image frame being input to this block, you would simply enter `vidfunc(u)` for your *MATLAB function*.

Now, based on the input going to the `MATLAB Fcn` block, and the fact that you have a Video Viewer block connected to the output, `vidfunc` should be structured such that it operates on a single image frame as its input and outputs another single image frame.  If `vidfunc` is not structured in this way, you will need to edit it (or just re-implement the same functionality using Simulink blocks).

That said, let's assume that `vidfunc` is also returning an M-by-N matrix representing a processed image frame.  You will want to set the *Output Dimensions* parameter for your `MATLAB Fcn` block to `-1` to indicate that the output will have the same dimensions as the input.  Also, (as indicated in the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html)) you will want to make sure *Collapse 2-D results to 1-D* is **unchecked** or else your image output will be in the form of one long vector rather than an M-by-N matrix.

Provided that `vidfunc` is structured correctly, this should solve your problem.

**NOTE:** To make your life a lot easier, I would strongly suggest displaying the signal data type and dimensions in your Simulink model.  This can help to avoid a lot of confusion.  This [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/toolbox/simulink/ug/f15-90106.html) describes exactly how to do this.

**--UPDATE--**

After looking at your code, this confirms my suspicion that the inputs/outputs of `vidfunc` are inconsistent with what your Simulink model expects. The way that you proceed is highly dependent on what your own design constraints are and what you actually want out of this system.  Basically, your Simulink model and MATLAB function disagree... which one is right? I'll give some general thoughts based on my best guesses at what you're aiming for.

First, Simulink is passing an image (in the form of an M-by-N matrix) into `vidfunc`. This means that `vidfunc` no longer needs to load an image at the start of the code.  So I believe that you could update the first few lines of code to be as such:

```
function h=vidfunc(a)
BW = edge(a,'sobel'); %sobel edge detection
```

See that now `vidfunc` is taking the actual image (not the filename that contains the image) as its input. Basically, you are removing the `a=imread(u);` line and jumping right in to processing `a`.

The other issue is the output of `vidfunc`. Simulink is expecting the output to be an image, but it is not. I'm not 100% sure what `h` is supposed to be in this code (when I first glanced at your code I thought these were handles to line objects but that doesn't seem to be the case).  It looks to possibly be the y coordinate of the endpoint of one of the houghlines.  Nevertheless, it's not what your Simulink model is expecting.  This one is not as straight-forward to fix.  Possibly you could try to use [getframe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) to grab an image from the plot of your lines.

I actually feel that the best advice that I can give to you is to just ***scrap the MATLAB function and implement everything in Simulink***. I think this will be a lot easier than trying to get `vidfunc` to play nicely with your model. `vidfunc` does not actually contain that much code, so this should not be too difficult of a task for you. Another benefit is that at the end of this process you'll have a nice Simulink model that explicitly shows all of the image processing steps that you are taking.

I believe that all of the image processing that you are doing with MATLAB functions can also be done with Simulink blocks (see the *Simulink Blocks* section of this [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/filters-transforms-and-enhancements.html)).

Good luck.

Comment: Sir if I write 'u' as an input argument to the vidfunc I still get error 'Input strings must have one row'.  vidfunc is simply taking one frame at a time; then its extracting region of interest and then I have applied sobel edge detection and then lastly Hough Transform is used. Actually the problem is  matlab function block needs an argument in file name parameter e.g in case of image I gave it as myfunction('a.jpg').Now I cannot write it as myfunction('video.avi') because it is taking a frame not the whole video at one time instant.How to write this? Is this the issue or something else.

Comment: If you can, update your original post to include your MATLAB code. From your description, it sounds like that's where your issue is coming from. You said that the first thing `vidfunc` does is load one image at a time from your video. However, `vidfunc` no longer needs to perform this file loading step because you are loading the video in Simulink and passing in a single image frame directly to the function.  So, as discussed in my post, you should remove the part of `vidfunc` that deals with loading the video file and iterating through frames. Just keep the part that processes a frame.

Comment: Sir I have updated my post by including the code. Please guide me where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: @ShayanAli - Quickly glancing at your code, I see two issues. 1) `vidfunc` is taking an image file name as input, and 2) it is returning an array of handles to line objects. Based on the way your Simulink model is structured, `vidfunc` needs to be rewritten to take the actual image as its input (in your case this is variable `a`). Also, it would need to output an image. So this makes me wonder, if basically all of the work is being done by your function, why are you trying to use this in Simulink? What is the output that you want from this whole process? This will greatly affect how to proceed

Comment: I have missed some blocks in my model I have uplaoded my model again at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1zzj3o1&s=6 . Sir I have tried all tips which you have told me but my model is not running; as it is still not picking one frame and processing it in the matlab function.

Comment: @ShayanAli Can you post the updated version of your matlab code. Also are you getting any specific error messages (post if so). Also what are the parameter settings for the matlab function block now. Perhaps that will need to be changed since the form of your inputs and outputs have changed.

Comment: Sir it would be better if I first explain you my problem actually the avi file Which I am having is of road & I am trying to detect road lanes using hough transform.Firstly I tried to implement that in simulink but it was not working;then I have written matlab function for it & tried to use that in my simulink model.If I load that video in matlab and then run that it works well but its giving me tough time in simulink. If I use the same model for an image its working but when I run that for my video then its not working. one thing more sir how will my inputs change for the updated model. –

Comment: Can you post the updated version of your MATLAB code.  Also, when you say it's not working, are you getting error messages (if so post them) or is it just that your output is not what you intended/expected?

Comment: Sir simulink has blocks for implementing hough transform but when I use them the road lanes are not detected although I have confined hough to my region of interest;so you can say that its not working in the way as I want it to work. I have uploaded the model at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1zb5rsw&s=6 Can you guide me how can I implement it properly.

Comment: I imagine that you have already reviewed this, but if not take a look at this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/feature-detection-extraction-and-matching.html#bp92qwb-1). The built in Simulink example `ex_vision_detect_lines` does pretty much exactly what you are looking for (with the exception of the ROI block). I suggest plotting the output of `Hough Lines` in a scope to see if it is actually outputting what you want. Perhaps your model works fine but the lines are just not being visualized well (like maybe `Draw Lines` is drawing a white line on a white section of your image).

Comment: Thankyou sir for your guidance.Sir actually in ROI block I have cropped the road lanes from the video and then I am applying hough to only those lanes so hough should detect them; but its giving me only one line in the area which is not even the part of ROI. Do guide me what could be the issue. Thankyou once again. I will follow the steps which you have mentioned above & will let you know if I will be having some issue.

Comment: Okay, one issue may be that `Hough Lines` is going to output the coordinates of the line relative to the *ROI* not to your original images.  You can confirm this by using the output of `Define ROI` as the image input to `Draw Shapes` and seeing if the lines are now drawn in the correct place.  If this is the issue, then this just means you need to add an offset to the output of `Hough Lines` to "convert" from ROI coordinates to the original images coordinates.

Comment: In order to find more lines, you'll need to increase the `Maximum number of local maxima` parameter in your `Find Local Maxima` block. Keep in mind that this may require you to change your Selector blocks, as well, to accommodate the new dimensions of the `Find Local Maxima` output, as this output will now be a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Thankyou sir for your guidance and help you don't have the idea how much you have helped me.Sir I have attached the output of 'Define ROI' as the image input to 'Draw Shapes' and now the lines are approximately at their position but sir I have no idea how to add an offset to the output of Hough Lines to "convert" from ROI  coordinates to the original images coordinates.Can you please guide me.

Comment: Take a look at the doc for the [Draw Shapes block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/drawshapes.html).  It looks like there is a setting that allows you to specify the region of interest. Set the `Draw shapes in` parameter of this block to `Specify region of interest via port`. According to the doc, "When you select this option, the ROI port appears on the block. Enter a four-element vector of integer values, [x y width height], where [x y] are the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the area."

Comment: ok Sir actually I am having matlab-2009 & this feature is not available in it so I think I should first install matlab-2012 & then try it. I will let you know if I will be having some issue. Thankyou

Comment: This should be available in 2009, but you have to enable it.  Read through [this doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2009a/toolbox/vipblks/index.html?/help/releases/R2009a/toolbox/vipblks/ref/drawshapes.html&http://www.mathworks.com/searchresults/?q=draw+shapes&searchArrow.x=0&searchArrow.y=0&searchArrow=search&c%5B%5D=r2009a) for the MATLAB 2009a version of the `Draw Shapes` block). As I said in my last comment, you have to open the parameter dialog for the block, and select `Specify region of interest via port` for the `Draw shapes in` field.

Comment: In general, you'll save yourself a lot of hassle down the road if you carefully read through the documentation for each of your blocks. Matlab/Simulink's online doc is an extremely useful tool.

Comment: ok Sir Thankyou I will follow it. Sir if I will define my ROI in draw shapes block then is there any need of 'define ROI block' in the start.

Comment: My understanding is that you need to use both.  I believe that the region of interest setting in `Draw Shapes` is simply letting that block know that the lines that you will be drawing have coordinates that are with respect to the specified region of interest rather than with respect to the entire image.

Comment: Sir My updated model is uploaded at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24wx15f&s=6. I have uploaded the frame of my road video at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2wp8c9e&s=6. The parameters which I have used for the 'Define ROI block' are uploaded at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24f9vo8&s=6. The video frame after cropping is uploaded at http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2lbe59s&s=6. Now the issue is I am using the same parameters for ROI port in Draw shapes block as I have used for Define ROI block but it shows no detected lines in the video. The parameters used is a vector=[120 10 60 290].

Comment: what could be the issue sir. I even tried to change the values but its giving me nothing at the end.

Comment: You might just have the ordering mixed up on the ROI input to `Draw Shapes`  According to the doc, the input is a "4-element vector of integers [x y width height], that define a rectangular area in which to draw the shapes. The first two elements represent the one-based coordinates of the upper-left corner of the area. The second two elements represent the width and height of the area."  So it's looking for [x y width height] and I think you are doing [y x height width].

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure, but I think that instead of creating a vector with a mux, you should just input it directly from the constant block.  So don't have 4 constant blocks with the values 20, 120, 290, and 60.  Have one constant block with the value [20, 120, 290, 60]. A constant block doesn't have to just be a scalar.

Comment: Sir its interesting to note that the parameters which I have given to ROI block (which are working perfectly for it); are not working when I give them as an input to draw shape block. I get a white line detected in the area which is not a part of my interest. I have uploaded the frame with detected white line at  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vmizhd&s=6. I hope that white line will be visible to you.

Comment: what could be the issue. I am also trying by varying the parameters. Thank you once again for your time, guidance & help. Seriously I have no words to thank you...

Comment: At this point I think your guess is as good as mine.  You're probably in a better place than me to be able to answer these types of questions. You'll just have to go through some good old fashioned debugging. I suggest making use of plenty of scopes and [Display blocks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/display.html) in order to figure out exactly what is happening at each stage of your model. You may need to experiment a little bit with that `Draw Shapes` block to learn exactly how it works. Maybe make a new model, feed some known inputs into `Draw Shapes` and see how it behaves.

Comment: Sir simulink gives points evaluated through hough transform as <4x1x251 int32>.                                              val(:,:,1) =

          46
           0
          54
         290
val(:,:,2) =

          46
           0
          54
         290  .......................                                                      I am having no idea how to analyse it; what information does it giving to me. Fristly I analyzed the hough transform in matlab mfile; over there I got a structure of lines corresponding to each lane detected which can be easily analysed.